# Missing records from Sales WTD calculation

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am calculating Week To Date sales from Sales-Transaction-Fact using a data filter driven from my date table BI-Date-Dim. The DAX runs fine for the majority of the records but it ignores a small handful of records from the calculation.

There are definitely sales for the records I'm looking for within the given date range. I've also checked that the date format on the joining date fields is the same format.

The DAX is

Current Year Volume (KG) =
CALCULATE(
'SALES-TRANSACTION-FACT'[Total Volume (KG)]
, FILTER('BI-DATE-DIM', 'BI-DATE-DIM'[Year] = MAX('BI-DATE-DIM'[Year]) && 'BI-DATE-DIM'[Fiscal WeekNo] < [TODAY-FISCAL-WEEKNUM] )
)

[TODAY-FISCAL-WEEKNUM] is calculated as

TODAY-FISCAL-WEEKNUM = LOOKUPVALUE('BI-DATE-DIM'[Fiscal WeekNo],'BI-DATE-DIM'[Date],TODAY())

I have also tried adding a column to the BI-DATE-DIM table that CONCATENATES the Fiscal WeekNo and Year and using that but it renders the same result.

The relationship between SALES-TRANSACTION-FACT and BI-DATE-DIM is MANY-ONE and the cross filter is set to single.

Any ideas?